# Getting the fields from the object using Php

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my php page containing the object from the session,

```
session_start();
$total = $_SESSION['totallist'];
```

How to get the fields from the object that is getting from the session of php. As I am very new to php, even gone through some process like foreach, $array, ... but no use. I am having some fields,arrays in the $totallist which is coming from the another php page which i stored in the session.Thanks, If any help.

While accessing the data from $total->totalid or even $total[0];$total[1]; it showing me as following

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\zustshop20th\failure.php on line 12

Invalid Transaction. Please try again[object Object]
```

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION['$totallist']);` if the result is the form of array then retrieve the session variables with foreach or any echo method.

Comment: Thanks @JeesKDenny, I am getting the values as [object object], but i want to get the fields from those object.

Comment: $total[0]; $total[1]; you can take each variable in the case of array.

Comment: i have edited my question please check it once

Comment: You should use $total["$totallist"] but i dont know why u add $ to the name of key and we dont see what exacly your session array got ...

Comment: You need to debug `print_r($total);` inside the loop. Also, please post your code snippet so it will be more helpful to know what are you trying to do.

Comment: I am getting the result as  [object object] from the session which i posted from another php page and stored in the session

Comment: Ok, I guess all the items under `$_SESSION['$totallist']` are not objects. hence you are getting the `non-object` error. So wrap a condition `is_object($total)` before you access `$total->totalid`

Comment: Thanks @Jeet, can i have a fiddle. As i am completely new to php. so that  i can use it

Comment: `
session_start();
$total = $_SESSION['totallist'];

if is_object($total) {
 print_r($total->totalid);
 // This shouldn't throw non-object error.
}
`

Comment: Yes i used the same concept, but its showing me as,                                 Array ( [0] => [objectObject] )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118499/discussion-between-nitin-agarwal-and-jeet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to help you

```
<?php
session_start();
$total = $_SESSION['totallist'];
if is_object($total) { 
    print_r($total->totalid); // This shouldn't throw non-object error. 

    // Then loop through.
    if (is_array($total->totalid)) {
        foreach($total->totalid as $k => $value) {

            // here collect $value as your required object.
            print_r($value);

        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jeet. for all ur efforts.  i Tried it. But, no use. I have an object as {"totalid":234,"totalname":"nitin"} which i am posting it to a php page using angularjs controller and storing it in $_SESSION and trying to get those in another page which shows me object as [object object].... but while encoding and decoding and printing in console shows me null values... Any suggestion will help me a lot